# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ElementAt[WebSecurity.CurrentUserId]

Tags: linq-to-entities

```
@accounts.UserProfiles.ElementAt(item.AuthorID).ProfilePicture
```

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Collision.Models.UserProfile
>   ElementAt[UserProfile](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Collision.Models.UserProfile],
>   Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `ElementAt` nor `ElementAtOrDefault` is supported in LINQ to Entities.

You can find list of all supported method on MSDN: [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`ElementAt(x)` and `ElementAtOrDefault(x)` are *not* supported: [.NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738474%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [.NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

However, you could use

```
source.Skip(x).First()
```

or respectively

```
source.Skip(x).FirstOrDefault()
```

to achieve similar results.

Note that `Skip()` requires its source to be sorted (with an 'OrderBy' clause).

Comment: It helped me to do it in cshtml : @{int counter = 0;} @foreach(...) { source.Skip(counter).First() //Do something   counter = counter +1;}

Comment: @MuratMercan Are you saying it's an off by one error? If you want the first element (x=0), you'd do `.ElementAt(0)` which is the same as `.Skip(0).First()`, not `.Skip(-1).First()`

Comment: Hi Cristi you are definitely right i didnt think that trough before commenting it, and it brings some methods on my libraries to fix :)